# Python error while configuring mesos on centos

Tags: python, linux, centos, mesos

I am trying to install mesos on CentOs. I downloaded it and run `./configure` command. But couldn't be completed due to installed version of python as mesos requires development version 2.6. I tried to upgrade python but it upgrades to 2.4 only. Then I manually download python 2.6 and install, which is located under `/usr/local/bin/` and the old one is located under `/usr/bin`. When I run the python command in terminal it displays python 2.6, but again when I configure mesos it again gives same error.

> configure: error: in `/root/mesos-0.14.1':
>   configure: error:
>     Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
>     installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
>     via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
>     Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
>     ============================================================================
>      ERROR!
>      You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
>      for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
>     ============================================================================

I then create symbolic link of `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python` but now 'yum' command doesn't work also configuring mesos again gives same error. I also tried `./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib/python/lib"` .What should I do to install mesos cluster in Cent Os ? What is the solution ?

Comment: Did you try installing python from source? if I recall for CentoOS, you should do ./configure, then make, then make altinstall

Comment: I downloaded tar file for python 2.6.6 and did ./configure, then make and make altinstall. But the error is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

you need to have python dev version (headers etc.)

try

yum install python-devel